# Where in the north of the UK are locations with good and easy to locate fossils?

Tags: uk, fossils, fossil-hunting

Following on from [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7758/beginners-guide-to-fossil-hunting?noredirect=1#comment16368_7758) there was a map of the good areas in Northern America where there are

> significant dinosaur fossil formations.

Where in the UK would this be the case?

Just to narrow this a little. I am aware of the Jurasic coast in Dorset (mantioned by nivag and aravona) but that's about 150 miles away from me ([in North wales](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Treuddyn,+Mold,+Flintshire+CH7/@53.1148542,-3.1214929,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487acf1fae4768c1:0x988154851a5f2acb)), So I'm more after somewhere in the North of England/north wales or failing that a map of the whole of the UK like in the answer to my previous question

Comment: I know there are some on the south coast. There is an area called the Jurassic coast after all. Quick search gives this guide from the national trust. http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/article-1355830164461/

Comment: I have a feeling the UK has been scoured for fossils for hundreds of years. Good luck finding anything easily.

Comment: @ShemSeger oh you can still find fossils down on the South coast even though people fossil hunt there every year :) might not be a good quality one, but they will be there.

Comment: @Aravona - Guess the ocean keeps uncovering new ones eh?   Makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote UK Fossils, picking out a few of the many areas they suggest where Fossils are Common or Often Found in the North:

**North Wales:**

> The North of Wales is well known for is Carboniferous limestone rocks. These rocks contain fossils of corals, brachiopods, and crinoids. Some of the most popular areas to collect are on Anglesey. The best locations here are at Caim and Great Ormes Head.

Areas include: Caim, Great Ormes Head, Moel Findeg and Burley Hill

**Yorkshire:**

> The Yorkshire coast is the second most popular area in the UK for fossil hunting. The same Jurassic fossils, famously found along Dorsets heritage coastline can be found here.

Areas Include: Port Mulgrave, Kettleness, Whitby and Saltwick Bay

**Scotland:**

> Most of the fossil bearing sites in the Midland and Grampian of Scotland area are along the Eastern coast. Here, the Carboniferous rocks yield plant remains, brachiopods, trilobite tracks, giant millipede tracks, corals and crinoids.

Areas Include: East Wemyss, Crail, Kinghorn and St Monans

[UK Fossils](http://www.ukfossils.co.uk/main.htm) have a **good map** where you can pick a location (eg, North Wales) and it will list all the areas where you can look for fossils, how common they are, and what period the fossils are from.

Comment: Ahhh, [this is what I need](http://www.ukfossils.co.uk/North%20Wales.htm)

Comment: @Liam glad I could help! :) we've gone fossil hunting a few times down at Lyme Regis (always packed) but this site gives a great guide on other locations and seems updated often enough.

Answer (score 3):

Whitby is a good place to start. The East Cliff area of the town below the Abbey is accessible at low tide.

From Church Street, find the Duke of York pub (good for a post explore pint) and take the steps down to a small beach. Walk across the beach and up the ramp to the far pier. On the other side of the pier, the shore is rocky and has limited sand. Up against the cliff face, you will easily find fossils such as palm fronds that can be prised free from the rock.